# @media print in any IE

Tags: css, joomla, joomla2.5

I'm trying to hide parts of my page for print. Found a solution with `@media print` and added this code to my page:

```
@media print
{    
    .no-print, .no-print *
    {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

Then I've added the class="no-print" to divs I didn't wont to print. Works like magic on Chrome but IE (8-11) ignores it completely and print all objects. 
You can see the print function in the following [page](http://rom.guywalderonline.com/index.php/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%92%20%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%97%D7%95%D7%AA/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%97%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%91%D7%99%D7%95%D7%91/%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%98%D7%A8%2045/%D7%91%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%A1%20%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%98%D7%A8%2045/5b%20%D7%91%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%A1%20%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%98%D7%A8%2045-detail).

You can see that the print icon and the green tabs are not show in Chrome but are in IE.
BTW, on FireFox for some unknown reason I don't even see the print icon... /:

Thanks in advance for any help provided,

Guy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your method won't work on IE. IE is a pain.

Adding a stylesheet like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://rom.guywalderonline.com/templates/shaper_istore_ii/css/print.css" type="text/css" media="print"  />
```

and adding your print specific CSS to the print.css file works for me in IE.

This is what the free AddPrintStylesheet extension does: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-a-design/print-a-pdf/20611

Comment: Hi Neil, thank you for your response. I've moved the code to a separate print.css file and imported it in the head. Still not working on IE and not on FireFox...